# Help me on App distribution certificate

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have distribution certificate on my machine. if i want to distribute the app from another machine what i have to do?

Is that possible?

Please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the instructions in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html)?